# Calculation that results in 222222328186035px

Tags: javascript, css, kendo-ui

Does this number has any significance?

On one computer from a guy at our company, the Kendo Popup plugin i'm using is incorrectly positioned and the inline style is clearly a miscalculation.

Just wondering what's up as this is such an odd problem.

Searching google for 222222328186035px yields a few results but nothing that explains whats up.

Comment: `42` is interesting number too...‮

Comment: I would guess you are concatenating strings, instead of adding numbers.

Comment: Mysery! But i think there is no other solution.

Comment: what is the question?! whether we find this particular number interesting?

Comment: Happens on only one specific computer at work and the environment (windows, chrome version etc) is identical to every other computer that work fine (this computer works fine with FF and IE). Since the number comes up quite a bit when doing a google search, it means other computers have had this problem, but nobody ever described it.

I guess I was hoping for the off chance that another user had encountered the problem. ie. (the following is completely made up) "You probably have a 64 bit operating system, there is a potential overflow because you divided something by something else" and so on.

Comment: Why so many downvotes? The OP showed research efforts, and the post below seems to be a plausible answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oh I found it. :)

Someone probably did 2 / 9 (or a similar fraction) in "float" precision and then printed at a higher precision than "float" accurately stores.

In C

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    printf("%.2f\n", (float)(20 / 9.0));
}
```

Output:

```
0.22222232818603515625
```

Comment: interesting, entering `2.0/9.0` into Chrome console displays `0.2222222222222222`

Comment: @akonsu, yes, I wonder if there's a way to decrease and then increase the precision of a number in JS, like I've done with the C code above.

Comment: Woah, that ticked me off, went to check and this specific computer browser was at zoom level 90%. This helped me fix the problem. Thanks alot.